# Need to Include a Name with Group By oracle sql

Tags: oracle

I have some Code here,

```
`SELECT a.Officer_ID, Count(Crime_ID)
FROM Officers a inner Join Crime_Officers b on a.Officer_ID =     b.Officer_ID
Group by a.Officer_ID
Having (Count(Crime_ID) > (select avg(distinct(Count(Crime_ID))) 
                      From Crime_Officers
                      Group by officer_Id));`
```

it outputs this,

```
`OFFICER_ID COUNT(CRIME_ID)
---------- ---------------
111115               9 `
```

Its cool and all, but my assignment only needs the officers last name which is in table A. I tried it with the Officer_ID and Count just to make sure the code was working. When I try it like this,

```
`SELECT Last
FROM Officers a inner Join Crime_Officers b on a.Officer_ID = b.Officer_ID
Group by a.Officer_ID
Having (Count(Crime_ID) > (select avg(distinct(Count(Crime_ID))) 
                      From Crime_Officers
                      Group by officer_Id));`
```

I get this error,

```
`Error starting at line 1 in command:
SELECT Last
FROM Officers a inner Join Crime_Officers b on a.Officer_ID = b.Officer_ID
Group by a.Officer_ID
Having (Count(Crime_ID) > (select avg(distinct(Count(Crime_ID))) 
                      From Crime_Officers
                      Group by officer_Id))
Error at Command Line:1 Column:8
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:`
```

Can anyone help or explain what I'm missing/Doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only select a column if a) it's in the GROUP BY, b) it's derived from a GROUP BY column or c) it's the result of an aggregate function like MAX/MIN.

In your case, each `Officer_ID` should only have one `Last` value.

Simply change your GROUP BY to read:

```
GROUP BY a.Officer_ID, a.Last
```